# Note able to import gi module on vscode ubuntu

Tags: python3, pip, voice-recognition

```
 /home/don_quixote/anaconda3/bin/python "/home/don_quixote/Desktop/voice assistence/voice.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/don_quixote/Desktop/voice assistence/voice.py", line 12, in <module>
    speak("hello Abhishek")
  File "/home/don_quixote/Desktop/voice assistence/voice.py", line 10, in speak
    playsound.playsound(filename)
  File "/home/don_quixote/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playsound.py", line 91, in _playsoundNix
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to install it using `pip3 install PyGObject` or it may be `pip install PyGObject`. You also might need to prefix the commands with `sudo` depending on your install.